# Average of System.Collections.Generic.List<(float[],float[])>

Tags: c#

I have a list of tuples of arrays of floats - `List<(float[], float[])>`. I want to calculate the average of all the floats in all the arrays in all the tuples in the list.

That is, how do I average all of floats contained in this list?

Comment: That type doesn't compile. Try this: Declare a variable of whatever type this list is:
`List<Something>`. When it compiles, copy it and paste it into this question. As-is the question is "broken." We can't tell what is in this list. (I'm guessing it's a list of two-dimensional arrays of floats, but that's just a guess. It could also be a list of a tuple of `float[], float[]`.

Comment: @ScottHannen There's much wrong with this question - but the type isnt it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/cfpA7c - Its just a list of Tuples.

Comment: Hi Scott Hannen ! Thanks you for answer. The timefreq is include 15 array 1024x1024.

Comment: Is the question: Given a `List<Tuple<float, float>>`, how do I average the `float`s? If that's it, you can just ask that and remove everything else.

Comment: What are you actually trying to average? Each of the 2 elements of the tuple. The average of Item1 & Item2 for the entire list. It's entirely unclear what you're trying to do. Show some input and expected output

Comment: Thanks you for answer! i really dont know that i am beginer and i search google but i dont find answer. Please help me.

Comment: i try to find average of timefreq as np.mean did.

Comment: (These are not answers! They are comments - we're trying to help you write a good question before we answer)

Comment: I'll try again - it is not clear what you are trying to get the average of. You have a list of 2 sets of floats. What are you trying to average. Show some example input and what you expect as output

Comment: Thanks Jamiec! the output is one number. That is average of all float[] in var timefreq

Comment: `timefreq` is a list of 2 sets of further arrays of floats. You want to average every single number in that list of 2 arrays?

Comment: it is the mean of all elements. type in C# System.Collections.Generic.List<(float[], float[])>.

Comment: Sorry everybody! I'm not an english speaker. Perhaps this makes it difficult

Comment: Does this accurately describe the question: "I have a list of tuples of arrays of floats - `List<(float[], float[])>`. I want to calculate the average of all the floats in all the arrays in all the tuples in the list. That is, how do I average all of these values?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will take a `List<(float[], float[])>` and return the average of all the values in all the arrays in all the tuples in the list:

```
private float AverageAllValuesInListOfTuplesOfArraysOfFloats(List<(float[], float[])> input)
{
    // Create a new list which will contain the "flattened" list of 
    // float values.
    var allValues = new List<float>();

    // Iterate over all the tuples of arrays
    foreach ((float[], float[]) tupleOfArrays in input)
    {
        // in each tuple of arrays, add the items from both
        // arrays the the flattened list which contains all
        // the values.
        allValues.AddRange(tupleOfArrays.Item1);
        allValues.AddRange(tupleOfArrays.Item2);
    }

    // Now we've got one big list of values. Average it.
    return allValues.Average();
}
```

Comment: If this is what they actually want to do, then its a fine answer (and well done for having a go at answering a terrible question). But Im willing to bet this is not what they actually want to do! Casting a close vote as needing more details may have been more useful in the long term

Comment: From the comments it looks pretty certain. I edited the question to clarify it. It looks like edit was reverted.

Comment: I reverted it. Theres a subtle difference between `List<Tuple<float[],float[]>>` and `List<(float[],float[])>` - I think your edit changed the meaning.